# Multiple textfiles from one variable VBScript

Tags: vbscript, output, createfile

I have a little VBScript code to collect data from properties and write them to files.

It is fully working but the output should only contain one single line every time.
For 10 objects 10 files with a single line.
But there are some objects which have variations and thats why the output file contains two or more lines.

Would you please help me with your ideas?

The variable that contains the data is called `lGesamt`.

```
For Each lnkOberstoff In MwScriptObj.Links(fldOberstoff)
    lGesamt = ""
    Set objOberstoff = lnkOberstoff.object
    liefName = objOberstoff.Property(1482).Value(0)
    liefArtikel = objOberstoff.Property(1801).Value(0)
    saison = objOberstoff.Property(1527).Value(0)

    For Each varcolor In objOberstoff.Variations(propDefFb)
    'VarNo = MwScriptObj.VarNoFromVarId(varcolor.value)
        Farben = ""                
        Farben = varcolor.Value
        Dim Lieferant
        Lieferant = objOberstoff.Value(prpLieferant, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim LieferantenArtikel
        LieferantenArtikel = objOberstoff.Value(prpLieferantenArtikel, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim Saison
        Saison = objOberstoff.Value(prpSaison, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim Thema
        For each lnkGtThema in objOberstoff.Links(fldGtThema)
            Set objGtThema = lnkGtThema.object
            Thema = objGtThema.Property(2577).Value(0)
        Next
        Dim LieferantenDessin
        LieferantenDessin = objOberstoff.Value(prpLieferantenDessin, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim Dessin
        Dessin = objOberstoff.Value(prpDessin, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim LieferantenFarbe
        LieferantenFarbe = objOberstoff.Value(prpLieferantenFarbe, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim MengeGeliefert
        MengeGeliefert = objOberstoff.Value(prpMengeGeliefert, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim SmsNutzbreite
        SmsNutzbreite = objOberstoff.Value(prpSmsNutzbreite, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim GewichtsEinheit
        GewichtsEinheit = objOberstoff.Value(prpGewichtsEinheit, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim GewichtBrutto
        GewichtBrutto = objOberstoff.Value(prpGewichtBrutto, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim Materialzusammensetzung
        Materialzusammensetzung = objOberstoff.Value(prpMaterialzusammensetzung, Nothing, varcolor)
        'Beschreibung
        Dim MaterialgruppenNr
        MaterialgruppenNr = objOberstoff.Value(prpMaterialgruppenNr, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim MaterialUntergruppenNr
        MaterialUntergruppenNr = objOberstoff.Value(prpMaterialUntergruppenNr, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim ERPNummer
        ERPNummer = objOberstoff.Value(prpERPNummer, Nothing, varcolor)
        Dim Firma
        Firma = objOberstoff.Value(prpFirma, Nothing, varcolor)
        lGesamt = lGesamt & Lieferant & ";" & LieferantenArtikel & ";" & Saison & ";" & Thema & ";" & LieferantenDessin & ";" & Dessin & ";" & LieferantenFarbe & ";" & Farben & ";" & Mengegeliefert & ";" & SmsNutzbreite & ";" & GewichtBrutto & Gewichtseinheit & ";" & Materialzusammensetzung & ";" & MaterialgruppenNr &  "/" & MaterialUntergruppenNr &  "/" & ERPNummer &  ";" & Firma & vbNewLine
        'MsgBox lGesamt & "lGesamt"
    Next

    lOutput = lOutput & lGesamt
    MsgBox lOutput
    desPath = "P:\Musterlaschenetiketten\"
    datName = saison & "-" & MwScriptObj.Property(4758).Value(0) & "-" & MwScriptObj.Property(4003).Value(0) & ".txt"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(desPath & datName)
    objFile.WriteLine(lOutput)
    objFile.Close
Next
```

[image: Sample Image msgbox]

This is the content from the output file:

```
Ipeker Tekstil A. S.;00553 Destiny;W8;T110;88361;745;;0335;;134;83G/QM;100CV;01/40/204;
Ipeker Tekstil A. S.;00553 Destiny;W8;T110;88361;745;IJ11/T200 frei;0935;;137;83G/QM;100CV;01/40/204;
```

These two lines should be in separate files.

Comment: Your problem description isn't clear to me. Please explain in more detail what doesn't work. Samples of desired and actual output usually help.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers okay I have corrected. Now all is in the question. And here again the description: okay sorry, the attached files will describe it better. You will see there the msgbox with the output. There are 2 Textblocks seperated with VbNewLine. I am trying to seperate the 2 text blocks each one in a file. Also You will see the Output file wich contains 2 lines, that is the problem I need always single lines in a file. I hope that clearified my problem. Thank You

Comment: Maybe `lGesamt` should be written to the file instead of `lOutput`?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Thank You but I get the same result with this(actually I get the same without lOutput but with an error Index out of Array thats why I am using the lOutput).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, what happens is this:

1. `objOberstoff.Variations(propDefFb)` returns 2 results, leading to 2 iterations of the inner loop.
2. Each iteration appends one line to `lGesamt`.
3. After the inner loop completes these 2 lines are concatenated to `lOutput` (which *should* actually cause each new file to contain *all* previously written data, unless you reset the variable at the beginning of the outer loop, just like `lGesamt`).

To fix the issue you need to stop appending to variables and move the code writing the output to the inner loop. You'll also need to add some kind of index to the output filename, otherwise subsequent iterations of the inner loop would overwrite the output file.

I would also recommend moving the definition of things that don't change inside the loop *outside* the loop (like the destination folder and the `FileSystemObject` instance).

Change your code to something like this, and it should do what you want:

```
dst = "P:\Musterlaschenetiketten"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each lnkOberstoff In MwScriptObj.Links(fldOberstoff)
    i = 1
    ...
    For Each varcolor In objOberstoff.Variations(propDefFb)
        ...
        lGesamt = Lieferant & ";" & LieferantenArtikel & ";" & Saison & ";" & _
                  Thema & ";" & LieferantenDessin & ";" & Dessin & ";" & _
                  LieferantenFarbe & ";" & Farben & ";" & Mengegeliefert & ";" & _
                  SmsNutzbreite & ";" & GewichtBrutto & Gewichtseinheit & ";" & _
                  Materialzusammensetzung & ";" & MaterialgruppenNr &  "/" & _
                  MaterialUntergruppenNr &  "/" & ERPNummer &  ";" & Firma

        fname = saison & "-" & MwScriptObj.Property(4758).Value(0) & "-" & _
                MwScriptObj.Property(4003).Value(0) & "_" & i & ".txt"

        Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(fso.BuildPath(dst, fname))
        objFile.WriteLine(lGesamt)
        objFile.Close
        i = i + 1
    Next
Next
```